# Android - Displaying all SQLite database entries in a ListView

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

What I am trying to do is display the contents of the database in a ListView. The layout contains a ListView which I have used and implemented but I can't seem to get them working together (or even the cursor), could someone give me a hand and an explanation of why my cursor implementation doesn't work?

I have a method to return the database entries as a Cursor:

```
public Cursor getAllRecords() {
     return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TEXT}, null, null, null, null, null);
 }
```

I have the class where I want to insert and display the database entries:

```
Button add;
EditText tM;
ListView generalList;
DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(this);

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        generalList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.generalList);

        Cursor c = dba.getAllRecords();
        c.moveToFirst();

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.id.generalList, c, new String[] {dba.KEY_TEXT}, new int[] {R.id.generalList}, 0);
            // This doesn't seem to work for me, I don't know how to fix it
            // or how to then get it working with the ListView

        generalList.setAdapter(adapter);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                insertIntoDatabase();
            }
        });
    }

 public void insertIntoDatabase() {
     dba.open();
     dba.insertRecord(textMessage.getText().toString());
     Toast.makeText(this, "Added:\n" + tM.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     dba.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a ListView with a CursorAdapter, the Cursor returned from the column must contain a column with the name _id uniquely identifying each row. I'm guessing that the one column you are fetching (dba.KEY_TEXT) is not named "_id". You can either add a column to your table named _id or when you perform your SELECT have the database return the name as _id

i.e.

```
SELECT col_name as _id FROM my_table;
```

OR

```
SELECT col_name _id FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

if the list contains only 1 `TextView`, you can use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead of your `R.id.generalList`.

and change the `new int[] {R.id.generalList}` to `new int[] {android.R.id.text1}`

like :

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, new String[] {dba.KEY_TEXT}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);
```

Comment: A null pointer exception in the class where the Cursor is used.

Comment: It is only opened in the insertIntoDatabase() method. Does it need to be opened for the Cursor too?

Comment: oh yeah, i think i typo `android.R.layout.simple_list_item1` to `android.R.id.simple_list_item1`, change that

Comment: yeah you have to open the database to obtain the cursor and its content

Comment: Changed both of those things but still getting errors! PS: At which point should the database be closed after opening it for the cursor?

Comment: Though this time I see the exception is saying 'column '_id' does not exist. So I'll need to look into that!

Comment: ok, you close your db when you have finished accessing the cursor.

Comment: Like this?      dba.open();
         Cursor c = dba.getAllRecords();
         dba.close();

Comment: So if the database is not opened it causes null pointer exception as the database can;t be found?

Comment: put close() after setting the `adapter` should not have any errors.

Comment: I still have the error saying 'column '_id' does not exist, but that's probably my error somewhere...

Comment: check which line give you that error, Logcat will tell you that

Comment: *REALLY* amateur question here so sorry in advance... But how do I find the ling number in Logcat?

Comment: see your logcat and there should have written (YOURCLASS.java : #line) check that line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15927/discussion-between-aprian-and-tim)

Comment: By the way - I got this sorted :-)

Answer (score 1):

on the arguments that receives the simplecursoradapter, remember the layout it receives is the layout for the actual item not the listview. so remove the R.id.generalList from there, cause that is the id that identified the listview not a full layout. so replace that with a layout that contains a textview. now, on the int array goes the id of the textview that will show the text you want and on the string array pass on the names of the fields in the record read from the database. do as mentioned by aprian and know that you can customize items as much as you need.